# How to not let a user with a new role edit users that have administrator role?

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I just found out how to create a new role on Wordpress. So, I did something like this:

```
function suporte_role_creation() {
    remove_role('suporte');
    add_role( 'suporte', 'Suporte', array(
        'read' => true,
        'create_users' => true,
        'delete_users' => false,
        'edit_users' => true,
        'list_users' => true,
        'promote_users' => true,
        'remove_users' => false
    ));
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'suporte_role_creation' );
```

Now, my intention is to let the user that belong to this new role be able to edit all users, except users with administrator role. How do I do that? Is there a filter for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a filter for that?

Yup, there is, and the hook name is [`user_has_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/).

So try this, which worked for me in WordPress 5.6.1 <sup>(latest release as of writing)</sup>:

```php
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse_383109', 10, 4 );
function wpse_383109( $allcaps, $caps, $args, $user ) {
    if ( empty( $args[2] ) || 'edit_user' !== $args[0] ||
        ! in_array( 'suporte', $user->roles )
    ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    $user2 = get_userdata( $args[2] );
    if ( $user2 && in_array( 'administrator', $user2->roles ) ) {
        $allcaps['edit_users'] = false;
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
```

And with that, for example on the Users → All Users admin page (`wp-admin/users.php`), users with the Suporte role can see the list of Administrators on the site, but the Suporte users won't be able to edit an Administrator.

And if you wonder, here's what the above code or function does:

1. `empty( $args[2] ) || 'edit_user' !== $args[0]` — this ensures that the requested capability is `edit_user` and that a specific user ID (`$args[2]`) is provided. So for example, the condition is true when calling `current_user_can( 'edit_user', 123 )`.
2. `in_array( 'suporte', $user->roles )` — this checks if the user who is editing the specific user above has the Suporte role.
3. `$user2 && in_array( 'administrator', $user2->roles )` — this checks if the user who is being edited has the Administrator role.
4. `$allcaps['edit_users'] = false;` — if all of the three conditions above are met, then this code (temporarily) disables the `edit_users` capability for the user said in condition #2 above. And if you want, you can also disable other capabilities.. :)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.